# Вызов шаблонного конструктора копирования

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-с++

На собеседовании задали вопрос: как модифицирофать класс `A` так, чтобы вызывался шаблонный конкструктор копирования?

```
#include <iostream>


struct A {
    A() = default;

    template<typename T>
    explicit A(const T&) {
        std::cout << "template copy constructor";
    }
};


int main() {
    A x;
    A y(x); // использует неявный конструктор копирования
}
```

Ну я предложил удалить генерируемый:

```
struct A {
    A() = default;

    template<typename T>
    explicit A(const T&) {
        std::cout << "template copy constructor";
    }

    A(const A&) = delete;
};
```

Однако мне сказали, что это неверно. Вот сижу сейчас и думаю, что же от меня хотели.

Comment: Может быть имелось ввиду обьявить специализацию для данного шаблонного метода, где T это A

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov нет, нужно модифицировать класс

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov А сгенерированный конструктор копирования будет все равно иметь приоритет.

Answer (score 4):

Можно убрать `const`, тогда шаблонный конструктор будет предпочтительнее при инициализации неконстантной ссылкой:

```
template<typename T>
explicit A(T &) {
    std::cout << "template copy constructor";
}
```

Альтернативный вариант с вызовом через обертку:

```
template<typename T>
explicit A(::std::reference_wrapper<T const>) {
    std::cout << "template copy constructor";
}

A(A const & other): A{::std::reference_wrapper{other}} {}
```

Comment: Из вопроса это не следует, но насколько я понял, модифицировать сигнатуру этого метода нельзя, надо именно его вызвать

Comment: @Павел А вызвать этот метод без изменения сигнатуры вряд ли получится, так как при вызове шаблонного конструктора нельзя явно указать параметры шаблона.

Comment: кажется, нашёл способ

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение. Достаточно добавить `volatile` в удаляемый конструктор. Тогда неявный конструктор копирования не добавляется.

```
#include <iostream>


struct A {
    A() = default;

    template<typename T>
    explicit A(const T&) {
        std::cout << "template copy constructor";
    }

    A(const volatile A&) = delete;
};


int main() {
    A x;
    A y(x);
}
```

Comment: Так а в вопросе написано, что удаление генерируемого (точнее предотвращение генерации) - неверно.

Comment: @VTT неверно то, что я написал на собесе - оно не компилируется) А это работает

Comment: Ответ @VTT гораздо лучше, в Вашем ответе содержится извращение. Хотя и вопрос для собеседования пахнет им же.